# Can I write plugins to with CodeRush Express and use it?

Tags: coderush, coderush-xpress

I was trying to run this [example](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/07/23/code-providers-101-implementing-unimplemented-properties.aspx)
using coderush express edition but i did not get any output as shown in this site.

I followed the complete procedure as given in the blog, a new visual studio window opened but did I did not get the output as shown. So I wanted to know whether this plugin runs with Express edition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly should work.

Try this...

- Open the options **Ctrl+Shift+Alt+O**
- Navigate to **Core\Plugin Manager**
- Sort the list Alphabetically
- Is the plugin in this List?

  - If not then confirm that the dll is located in the correct folder.
  - It should be the folder listed as Community plugins folder at Detail at **Core\Settings**
- Is it listed as Loaded or unloaded?

  - if unloaded, try **double clicking** the plugin to trigger it loading.

Comment: Thank You Rory. The plugin was not loaded and it is working now.